# Stuck with handling Enter in android edittext

Tags: android, event-handling, android-edittext

I have multiple textBoxes. Each of them has a TextWatcher attached to it. Now I wanted to set an OnKeyListener for the last mandatory textBox, so I could handle Enter key. When Enter key is pressed in theis textBox, I want to set the text of this textBox to a default value, then I want to save data from all textBoxes, clear all textBoxes and set the focus to the first textbox, so the user can enter new data. However, obviously I cannot effectively requestFocus on any other TextBox or Button in the onKey-eventhandler of the TextBox.OnKeyListener.

```
myLastTextBox.setOnKeyListener( new EditText.OnKeyListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event!= null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Button  nextB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
            nextB.performClick(); //the function called validates all fields, 
                                  //saves the data to lists, sets all editText 
                                  //to "", requests focus to the first editText.                
            res= true;
        }
        else if (event!= null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER &&  event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            res=true; //consume also the keyUp event of the enter key.
        }
        return res;
    }
});
```

When the program returns from the onKey-event handler, the focus is still in the same textBox. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok, I wanted to simplify the question, but maybe I made it too easy. When Enter is pressed, I not only want to set the focus, but I want to call a function, that reads, saves, clears all textBoxes and then sets the focus to the first editText.

Comment: have you tried setting the next focus key in the XML layout? I think it might do what you're attempting out of the box

Comment: Thanks, tried this out, but that does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should look into IME actions. Let's say you have a layout with three `EditText` views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/confirm_password"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just by itself, this will handle movement between fields automatically and provide you with a "Next" button, instead of an enter key (for standard input methods).

Now, to intercept the last key (which will be "Go"):

```
final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
final EditText confirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);

confirm.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO == actionId) {
            String un = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String conf = confirm.getText().toString();

            username.setText(null);
            password.setText(null);
            confirm.setText(null);

            /* Save your stuff */
            // ...

            username.requestFocus();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a deeper look into IME actions and will give this a try in the evening. I would be glad if someone could point out what concept prevents the focus to be set to another element in the onKey event of the onKeyListener.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem and even the text of the Enter button becomes more readable.